# Apache Tika round-trip: Rebuild document using extracted text

Tags: apache-tika

Is it possible to use Apache Tika to extract text, modify the extraction and then inject it back to the original document?

I imagine it could be possible by modifying the parser code so it could be run again and reinsert text instead of extracting it, but is there any feature already to do this?

Useful for document translation.

Comment: Are you aware that the Apache Tika parsers deliberately simplify and normalise the content that they extract?

Comment: Actually, no, I don't know the inner workings. But I imagine there could be some scenarios where the "unnormalised" content could be left as is (like tagged html/xml) and used for "out of body" modification. (Maybe each text segment could receive an ID or something for mapping and later import). This wouldn't work on scenarios which are probably presented by PDFs, which contain a lot of "garbage" (note the quotes). Of course, if this proves to be overly complex, there's no point in using Tika. I just thought this could be a scenario experimented before and for which there is a solution.